# Python - Modifying lists within a list

Tags: python, list, loops

Consider myself a beginner with Python. I'm trying to do something I've not quite done before and am completely stumping myself.

Hoping someone can give me a clue as which path to take on this.

I have a number of lists within a larger list.

I would like to iterate through the large list and modify data in each sub-list. There are a number of common variables within each list, but not all lists will be the same.

#### Example:

```
LIST = [
        ['Name: Dave', 'Age 28', 'Dogs', 'Football',],
        ['Name: Tony', 'Age 22', 'Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']
       ]
```

The end goal is to have 1 large list with each sublist converted to a dictionary.

#### Goal:

```
LIST = [
        {'Dave' : { 'Age' : '28' } {'Likes' : ['Dogs', 'Football']}},
        {'Tony' : { 'Age' : '22' } {'Likes' : ['Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']}}
       ]
```

The conversion to dictionary I will worry about later. But I am struggling to get my head around working with each sub-list in a loop.

Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have to modify the list `LIST` "in place". Just create a new list (and if you must, reuse the name `LIST` for it afterwards)

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = []
for el in list1:
    list2.append( compute(el))
```

where compute is a method that will turn your list into the dictionary you want

Comment: Or just list comp. It's Python, why do we insist on making it more verbose for no gain in readability: `list2 = [compute(el) for el in list1]` Of course, if `compute` isn't a separate function, inlining a lot of complex work into a listcomp would be poor form; depends on code design.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Axnyff's answer is pretty much what you want</s>
ShadowRanger's comment on Axnyff's answer is definitely what you want. List comprehensions are really cool!

Simply iterating over the list with a for loop lets you work on each sub-list and do whatever you want to it.

It looks like you don't really want to modify the lists in place, rather you want to process each list into a dictionary (and extracting that process into a separate function is very good for readability), and put those new dictionaries into a new list.

EDIT:

Also, as correctly mentioned in a down-voted answer, your dictionaries should probably be in the form:

```
{'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 28, 'Likes': ['Dogs', 'Football']}
```

Unless you actually want to use the dictionary to find their information by their name, in which case this is the correct syntax:

```
{'Dave' : { 'Age' : 28, 'Likes' : ['Dogs', 'Football']}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = {}
temp = {}
for x in LIST:
      key = x[0][6:]
      key_1 = x[1][:3]
      value_1 = x[1][3:]
      key_2 = 'Likes'
      value_2 = x[2:]
      temp[key_1] = value_1
      temp[key_2] = value_2
      result[key] = temp
      temp = {}
```

Try this
but as you know dictionary has no sequence , no guarantee for age to be second in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to get your dictionary in both the ways mentioned by Tom Ellis.

```
LIST = [
    ['Name: Dave', 'Age 28', 'Dogs', 'Football', ],
    ['Name: Tony', 'Age 22', 'Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']
]

l = list()
for li in LIST:
    d = dict()
    likes_list = []
    for i in li:
        if "name" in i.lower():
            d.update(dict([i.replace(' ', '').split(":")])) #removing the whitespace for formatting.
        elif "age" in i.lower():
            d.update(dict([i.split()]))
        else:
            likes_list.append(i)
    d["likes"] = likes_list

    l.append(d)
print l
```

Which results in:

```
>>> [{'Age': '28', 'Name': 'Dave', 'likes': ['Dogs', 'Football']}, {'Age': '22', 'Name': 'Tony', 'likes': ['Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']}]
```

If you really want the dictionary in the format you stated first, you could **continue** with the program like this:

```
l2 = []
for element in l:
    nd = {}
    name = element.pop("Name").strip()
    nd[name] = element
    # print nd
    l2.append(nd)
print l2
```

Which results in the way you stated:

```
>>> [{'Dave': {'Age': '28', 'likes': ['Dogs', 'Football']}}, {'Tony': {'Age': '22', 'likes': ['Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']}}]
```

Answer (score -2):

```
LIST=[{'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 28, 'likes':['Dogs', 'Football']},{'Name': 'Tony', 'Age': 22, 'likes':['Beer', 'Star Wars', 'Hotdogs']}]
```

You Do like This, Thank You.